# How to generate parent/child nest on client side?

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, d3.js

I've searched through the myriad parent/child array/object/whatever questions here and elsewhere and haven't been able to solve my issue. I know this is a bit long, but I wanted to ensure I'm providing enough info to you guys.

Here's what I want to do:

1. I have a number of `<div>`-delineated items on the page with parent/child relationships, generated via php from my database
2. I want to use these items as the data source for a D3.js Dendrogram (a node-link tree diagram http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/cluster.html)
3. I'm storing them with left/right nested set values but also parentID values, so I can add ID, parentID, rgt, lft and depth attributes to the `<div>` elements, so I should have available whatever's needed to generate the parent/child relationships on the client side
4. For various reasons, instead of creating a JSON file on the server side to use as the data source, I need to create it on the client side based on the attributes in #3
5. I've had difficulty getting various suggested javascript functions to work and all the D3 examples I've found use either a preexisting JSON file or generated math-based file, not attributes of elements already on the page

Here is an example of what already works for me with the D3 Dendrogram, but it's not generated dynamically:

```
var tree3 = 
{"sid": "1", "children": [
    {"sid": "2", "children": [
        {"sid": "5", "children": [
            {"sid": "75"},
            {"sid": "85", "children": [
                {"sid": "87"}, ...
```

To give you an idea of where these attributes are in the DOM, I originally tried the below, but of course it doesn't generate any hierarchy:

```
function tree() {
    var tree=[];
    $("article").each(function(){
        tree.push({
            sid:$(this).attr("sid"), 
            l:$(this).attr("l"), 
            r:$(this).attr("r"),
            pid:$(this).attr("pid")
        });
    });
    return tree;
}
```

I've been messing around unsuccessfully with variants of the below to get a nested array:

```
function tree2() {
   $("article").(function(d) {
       return d.parent().attr("pid") === 0;
}, function(parent, child) {
    return parent.attr("pid") === child.parent().attr("sid");
}).toArray();
}
```

So, I'm driving myself crazy trying to create the javascript array nested correctly, but it's dawned on me that I may not need to and that D3's data selectors and methods could be sufficient.  Could you please help me with the code to:

1. Pull the needed attributes to generate the parent/child relationship within a D3 function ("sid" is the identifier) or, if this isn't possible,
2. Create the needed array or array-like object in javascript for use by D3 (still with "sid" as the identifier).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dude, if you worked this up in a JSFiddle, it would be much easier to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Fair point. Please see my comments below to @peteorpeter with JSFiddle set at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWalnut/hE7mY/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get recursive!  Basically the trick is to pass the *current* parent in as you go, which changes the context and allows you to walk down the tree.

**Update: [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hE7mY/4/).**

Assuming your HTML structure is something like this:

```
<div sid="1" pid="">
    <div sid="1.1" pid="1">
        <div sid="1.1.1" pid="1.1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could do something like this:

```
var _json = {};

function addTreeNode(div, parentObj) {

    var childObj = {
        sid: $(div).attr("sid"),
        pid: $(div).attr("pid")
    }

    // add this to it's parent in the JSON hierarchy
    if (!parentObj.children) parentObj.children = [];
    parentObj.children.push(childObj);

    // keep adding for all children div's
    $(div).find("div").each(function() {
        addTreeNode(this, childObj);
    });
}

// start at the roots, it will magically work it's way out to the leaves
$("body > div").each(function(){
    addTreeNode(this, _json);
});

console.log(_json);
```

Note that if your tree is big enough, you *will* cause stack overflows, especially in IE.  In that case, you'll need to switch this over [from recursion to iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration).  It's not as pretty that way, though.

Comment: Sorry, you're right @peteorpeter. The current HTML has the "pid" as the ParentID, referring to the "sid" of the parent, e.g., '<div sid="1" pid="0"> <div sid="2" pid="1"> etc.' so your assumption was correct.

Comment: I tried it on my page and it successfully ran, although it didn't seem to create the nest and pushed all child items under the single parent. I created a JSFiddle based on your code and dumped in some basic <div> data and over there it appears to be creating an empty object: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWalnut/hE7mY/3/) . Can't see what I'm messing up.

Comment: The markup you were using in the fiddle _wasn't actually nested_ as I had assumed. I [updated the fiddle HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/hE7mY/4/) and got the script working.

Comment: Okay, I think I see the source of the confusion...I apologize for not being more clear. The <div> tags are not nested on my page; the only way to tell the hierarchical relationship between them are the "sid" and "pid" tags...they're distinct elements on the page (that's why I didn't nest them on the fiddle). I need to create the nested relationships in an object so D3.js can know the relationships.

Comment: You can use the same pattern, then, you'll just need to replace the search for children `div`s from `$(div).find("div").each(...)` to something like `$("div[pid=" + div.attr('sid') + "]").each(...)`.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for all your help! (I would upvote your answer too, but I need two more reputation points first :)

Comment: One last question @peteorpeter: when I run your last code suggestion, I get "div is not defined." I assume it's the `div.attr` that's throwing it...any suggestions?

Comment: Probably should be `$(div).attr("sid")`.